# Convert complex query from Laravel to SQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, collections

I'm trying to move some statistics logic entirely to SQL to vastly improve performance, however it's quite complex and I'm not sure how to achieve this using procedures/functions in SQL - or whether it's even possible.

Stats table looks like this:

[image]

Row in the table looks like this:

[image]

This is the code I'm trying to convert. `$this->stats` is an Eloquent Collection of all the rows in the table:

```
return $this->stats
    ->groupBy(function ($stat) {
        return $stat->created_at->format('Y-m-d');
    })
    ->map(function ($stats) {
        $times = [];

        for ($hour = 0; $hour < 24; $hour++) {
            $thisHour = $stats->filter(function ($stat) use ($hour) {
                return (int) $stat->created_at->format('H') === $hour;
            });

            $times[$hour] = $thisHour->isNotEmpty()
                ? $thisHour->sum(function ($stat) {
                    return $stat->data->count;
                }) : 0;
        }

        return $times;
    });
```

This outputs something like this:

```
{
    "2018-12-20": {
        0: 54,
        1: 87,
        2: 18,
        3: 44,
        4: 35,
        ...
    }
}
```

So it's grouped by date, and each date contains 0-23 (the hours of the day) with the corresponding value (in this case the summation of the row's data->count property).

In a different query I've been able to get the summation of the data->count property by using this:

```
SELECT SUM(data->>\"$.count\") AS value
```

So is this even possible to do in SQL? I'm imaging there to be a date columns, plus the hours column, so hour_0, hour_1 etc. with the values underneath.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does the table look like?

Comment: This is not a database query but a Laravel collection with some functions. Where is `$this->stats` coming from?

Comment: Updated post - `$this->stats` is an Eloquent Collection of all the rows in the table

Comment: Added table pics too

Answer (score 1):

The first step I would take to understand how Laravel is doing it would be enabling query logging and dumping the query;

```
DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();
// ... do your query
$queries = DB::getQueryLog();
```

That will allow you to recreated the Eloquent query in plain SQL. From there, you can work on optimizing and condensing.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/database#query-logging

Comment: Oh sorry, perhaps I wasn't clear - the code I put above is from Laravel Collections, so `$this->stats` is just all of the rows in the table.

Answer (score 0):

**UDPATED**

As you have now included the table structure, the following query should give you required results in tabular format. You need to parse the results to convert to json.

**Updated SQL**

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(stats.updated_at, "%Y-%m-%d") AS `date`,
    HOUR(stats.updated_at) AS `hour`,
    COUNT(stats.id) AS record_count
FROM stats
GROUP BY `date`, `hour`
ORDER BY 1 ASC, 2 ASC
```

The resulting tabular data would look similar to this.

[image]

Comment: I've updated the answer to align to the table structure.